# MarkLogic - Quickest Way to Empty a Large Database

Tags: xquery, marklogic

What is the quickest way to empty a large database of documents in MarkLogic version 5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The absolutely fastest way to empty a database is to clear all the forests connected to it.
go to the Database in the admin GUI and find each forest. Then go to each forest and select Clear it will instantly delete all documents in the database.

If you want to do this programatically there is [this](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aforest-clear)

or

`xdmp:forest-clear(xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database("My Database")))`

Comment: There is also a Clear button on the Database configure page, which will issue a clear forest for each of the attached forests for you. Saves you quite some clicks if there are multiple forests connected to the database.